# Jekyll Bootstrap: Having trouble modifying the Liquid template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-bootstrap

I've worked with Rails before but I'm having issues working my way around configuring the layout that I`m using.

I am using the Twitter theme, and under `_includes/themes/_layouts/default.html`, I want to be able to link to other pages under the nav as opposed to the default. I understand that the pages are given by the `site.pages` variable but I don't know how to modify it.

```
      <ul class="nav">
        {% assign pages_list = site.pages %}
        {% assign group = 'navigation' %}
        {% include JB/pages_list %}
      </ul>
```

I want to link the `about.html` page that I have created using `rake page name="about.md"` to a subtopic under the navigation class as listed above.

In addition, how do I print out debugging statements? In ERB templating, I was simply able to print to the log, however something like `{{print "Hello"}}` is illegal, so what is the preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do, I think, is add `group: navigation` to your yaml header of `about.md`, and remained defalut navbar code unchanged. It put the `about.md` to the `navgation`group, `{% assign group = 'navigation' %}`, this code tell use `navgation`group generate navbar links

`about.md` yaml header like this

```
---
layout: page
title: About
header : About 
group: navigation
---
```

Comment: Solid. I did something similar to work-around not knowing how to do this, but thanks, this is cleaner.